# Sql comparing date columns with conditions

Tags: mysql

since I'm new here (and from Belgium), and rather unexperienced in advanced sql.
Hopefully you can help me solve a simple (but not for me) problem:
I have a large table with multiple columns containing dates.
I want to develop a query where i can filter all rows where f.e. the difference between date column a and date column b exceeds 3 months (example, can be another value)
Syntaxis suggestions?Thank you

Comment: The newness we can forgive, but Belgium?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: It shall be my undoing one day, I know... :-)

Comment: You really need to provide an example of what you've tried. Lacking that the question will almost definitely be closed.

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you ask a question, you should provide sample data and desired results.  This particular question is rather generic; it is possible to give a rather generic answer.

You would typically do this by adding three months to one date and comparing them.  Something like this:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.a > dateadd(t.b, interval 3 month);
```

This gets where `b` is 3 months after `b`.

If you want the comparison to be before *or* after:

```
select t.*
from t
where (t.a > dateadd(t.b, interval 3 month)) or
      (t.a < dateadd(t.b, interval -3 month));
```

Comment: Would you be so kind to introduce the columns please, doesn't seem to werk in PHPMyAdmin: `Date_Preliminary_Report`,`Date_Final_Report` from
`2_raf_decomposed_from_jan_2016` (table)

Comment: Solution found in using "TIMESTAMPDIFF", ty all!